# Why is NULL handled differently in aggregate and scalar functions?

Tags: sql, ansi-sql, database-agnostic

Let's take the following two queries:

```
select greatest(1, val) from unnest([null]) as val
# null
```

And:

```
select sum(val) from unnest([1, null]) as val
# 1
```

My question is why is `null` handled differently between aggregate functions and normal scalar functions? Of course, the second query is more useful when `null` values are not counted. But I would think the first one would be more useful as well if it were to return `1` instead of `null`. If `null` is an 'unknown value', then wouldn't both functions have a supposedly unknown answer (i.e., `null`), not just the latter?

If there is a historical reason for this it would be great to know as well. Hopefully someone can shine some light on why there's a difference between the two.

Comment: Basically because that's what the SQL standard decided back in the day I think. When ANSI Warnings are on SQL Server will print a message telling you NULLs are ignored in the aggregation. I'm assuming they thought this would be more useful in practice even if logically somewhat inconsistent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The aggregate functions are supposed to skip null values. Here is an excerpt from SQL-92 standard:

> <set function specification>
>
> [...]
>
> Otherwise, let TX be the single-column table that is the result of
> applying the <value expression> to each row of T **and eliminating
> null values**. If one or more null values are eliminated, then a
> completion condition is raised: warning- null value eliminated in set
> function.

The `greatest` function on the other hand should return null if any argument is null¹.

> My question is why is null handled differently between aggregate
> functions and normal scalar functions?

Generally speaking, scalar functions return null if any of their arguments is null². Here is [Ask Tom's take on this exact same issue](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:524526200346472289), I personally agree with everything that is said in the answer:

> ***and Tom said...***
>
> pretty much all single row functions return NULL if any of their
> inputs to compare are null.
>
> ```
> ops$tkyte%ORA10GR2> select round( 1.2, null ) from dual;
>
> ROUND(1.2,NULL)
> ---------------
> NULL
> ```
>
> when you ask "what is the greatest of 1, NULL, 2 - the answer is "we
> don't know, because NULL is unknown"
>
> Aggregates are defined to "skip nulls" (ANSI says so)
>
> But functions in general that take a set of inputs, will return NULL
> when a deciding input is NULL.
>
> http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm#i88893
>
> If you call a SQL function with a null argument, then the SQL function
> automatically returns null

¹ Different implementations of the greatest function existed long before it was standardized. [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) and [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/GREATEST.html) return null if any argument is null; while [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST) and [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-greatest-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest) ignore null values.

² Conversely, vendor specific scalar functions exist that skip null values. One example is `concat_ws` (MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server) function that is designed to simplify concatenation of (possibly null) strings using a separator.

Comment: GREATEST has been included in the SQL standard for several weeks now! SQL-2023 has it, and LEAST too. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2023

Comment: great, unfortunately specs are no available for free (afaik) so cannot say which of the above two behaviors is standard,

Comment: If any of its values is null, null is returned.

Comment: Sad for SQL Server and PostgreSQL. I'll revise the answer in a few hours. Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 1):

Without specific citation, reason may be due to a comparison function like `GREATEST` versus a computing function like `SUM`.

In ANSI SQL, comparing any value (using operators such as `<`, `>`, `=`, `<>`) to `NULL` should always return unknown or `NULL`. Interestingly, different RDBMSs may not by default follow this rule completely so `WHERE my_column <> NULL` can retun non-zero rows. See discussion in SQL Server's [**`SET ANSI_NULLS`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) mode. Also, see Postgres' [**`transform_null_equals`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-TRANSFORM-NULL-EQUALS) mode.

On other hand, also in ANSI SQL, `SUM` like most aggregate functions except `COUNT(*)` ignore `NULL`s. Hence, you observe the different behaviors.